# Circle on top of Circle not rendered correctly

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-shapes, hardware-acceleration

I came across this problem, when I tried to use the leaflet markercluster plugin to display clusters in a map.

Here are two screenshots, one made in FF36 and the other in IE11

Firefox: [image: Firefox circle]
Internet Explorer: [image: Internet Explorer Circle]

Somehow it seems the border of the inner circle isn't displayed correctly.
I tried with `background-clip` and setting the `border-color` but that seemed to have no effect at all.

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color:rgb(181, 226, 140);
}
.circle div {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color:rgb(111, 226, 140);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems fine in FF36.01.1 on W7 - http://jsfiddle.net/9d2stdg5/

Comment: I just found out, that when I start FF in safe mode, it is displayed correctly. But if i disable all addons manually the problem persists.

Comment: Figured it out. It's actually a problem with the hardware acceleration. I turned it off and now everything renders just fine.